# Insert at caret position with a Silverlight textbox

Tags: silverlight, textbox

In WPF you can insert at the caret position using the `CaretIndex` property. However this seems to be missing in the Silverlight textbox control.

Is it possible using a different technique?

Answer (score 6):

I also had the same problem. I used the SelectionStart property.

```
    private void QuotePrefixTextboxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)sender;
        var caret = tb.SelectionStart;
        tb.Text = tb.Text.ToUpper();
        tb.SelectionStart = caret; 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:-

```
 myTextBox.Select(position, 0);
 myTextBox.SelectedText = "Content to insert";
```

Comment: What's the position variable?

Comment: this worked for me, even though the field was bound, where the top method did not